# Tracing and timing every step of the initialization of the shell

Tags: zsh, profiling

The following command gives me the full trace of steps

```
zsh -i -c -x exit > trace 2>&1
```

I'd love for it to also capture, **next to each exact step** (e.g. as a first column), how long that step took.

Does Zsh provide an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily get something close (with reasonably recent versions): a timestamp on each step. From the [documentation of `-x`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-XTRACE):

> The output is preceded by the value of $PS4, formatted as described in [Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion).

You can put [a timestamp](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Date-and-time) in the trace prefix. `%.` gives you nanosecond precision with zsh ≥5.6, only microsecond precision between 5.0.6 and 5.5.x. I think that in earlier versions, which don't have `%D`, you can only get second precision.

```
PS4='+%D{%s.%9.}:%N:%i>' zsh -x …
```

You can then post-process the trace to calculate the differences between successive timestamps.

```
<trace awk -F: '{printf "+%.09f", $1 - t; t=$1; $1=""; print}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Guilles!  I got some some negative differences (negative time deltas) in the final result (e.g. `+-0.007487059 nvm 7>DEFAULT_IFS=$' \t\n'`). What do you think explains that? In case it helps, I run this in 5.62. Also, should I assume this diff is measured seconds (i.e. `0.007487059` is in seconds?)

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina Yes, the diff is in seconds. Now that I think about it, the awk code assumes that the commands run one after the other, but that's not true of commands running in the background (`… &`), of pipes (`… | …`), etc. I'm not sure if you can get precise information about this using `PS4`, You could print out the subshell level if `setopt prompt_subst` is enabled but that wouldn't be enough if commands are running in parallel. The next step up would be a DEBUG trap.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll look up how to do this with a DEBUG trap. Just in case - do you think the DEBUG trap could actually accomplish what I am discussing here correctly, or would it still leave out some execution paths / miscalculate time deltas?

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina I'm not aware of any specific gotchas, but I don't have much experience with it.